# Лишний пробел

Tags: php

Код выводит $post_title , но почему-то выводит с лишим пробелом на конце, есть способ избавиться от пробела?

```
else  {
 echo'<h1 class="art-postheader">';
 echo $post_title;
 echo'</h1>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

:-)

```
echo '<h1 class="art-postheader">', trim($post_title), '</h1>';
```

Comment: Ну тогда уж так

echo '<h1 class="art-postheader">'.trim($post_title).'</h1>';

Comment: Зачем? по-результату - одно и то-же, а вот по памяти - создаем лишнюю строку.

Comment: > по-результату - одно и то-же, а вот по памяти - создаем лишнюю строку.

Так вот из-за чего у всех неопытных кодеров сайты-то торомзят! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
else echo'<h1 class="art-postheader">'.$post_title.'</h1>';
```

так вот напиши :)